# Front controller freezes when uploading file to amazon s3

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3

I have a Symfony app which receives a .zip file, unzips it and then uploads all images to Amazon S3 (Using the PHP SDK 2), that's working nicely.

The problem is while it's uploading I can't use the front controller anymore, it has to wait until it finishes uploading. If I upload using app_dev.php I can't access any url based on that front controller until the upload finishes, app.php requests work just fine.

Is there a way I can somehow bypass that limitation? The code I'm using to upload is

```
$client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $this->container->getParameter('aws_bucket'),
    'Key' => $someKey,
    'Body' => fopen($somePath, 'r+'),
));
```

One solution could be, create another controller and use it to handle the uploads, but still, it could handle only one upload at a time...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your session is locking. Close the session before any long process.

```
$this->get('session')->save();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that log the user out? How exactly would I close the session? Pardon my ignorance but I'm not very experienced with Symfony yet.

Comment: No, it will only write the session file and close it. I think it should be $this->get('session')->save(); I'm not experienced with symfony2 either, I'm still stuck with version 1.4

Comment: Ah I see, now that I check, I can access with another browser just fine, looks like it is indeed the session locking. Googling on the subject I could find how to do it: "$session->save(); session_write_close();" Thanks a lot!

Comment: $session->save() should do session_write_close() already, that's what in documentation at least :)